# Is it possible to see only text while editing a large html file?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, editor

For going easy on my tired eyes, while editing a large documentation html file, I would like to temporary hide all html tags in order to see just plain text. However, it is important to be able to do that while keeping line breaks and blank lines. The problem is that tags, atributes, values and tabbing of all that in the code editor (VS Code) make a lot harder to focus, read, and edit the text alone.

I tried to change the tags, atributes and values' coloring to match that of the background, but that proved to be a hassle. I'm wondering if there is a switch or a specific configuration I could use to have the same result.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not exactly what you're looking for, I wanted to share it anyways - maybe it's suitable for you.

You could write your documentation using Markdown (there are also tools out there to convert HTML into md) and a editor like [Typora](https://typora.io), which renders the text live while you type it. You can then provide a custom CSS-File or use one of the standard ones and export it as a HTML file.

Comment: Thank you. I have used markdown before with a static generator (MkDocs). But for this particular project I am using a complex html template as my starting point to later insert it in Django framework. Being able to write text straight into the template file would be easier, if wasn't for so much tags, attributes, values and tabbings.